# Do the high-fashion armour clothings from Run & Gun that are tagged as 'Newest Models' lose armour rating over time?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5

Relevant rules snippets from Run & Gun, p. 59:

NEWEST MODEL

> These items are the most recent incarnations of their corporate 
>   creators. That means they lose a little more when purchased as 
>   Lightly Worn, namely a 20 percent loss of Armor Rating (round 
>   adjusted Rating up) when buying older models of the clothes.

LIGHTLY WORN

> The Lightly Worn option provides runners with a chance to buy 
>   some primo gear at a discount rate, with a few catches. Buying from 
>   the Lightly Worn section requires the character to have Armand as a 
>   contact with a Loyalty of at least 2. When gear is purchased Lightly 
>   Worn, the character gets a price discount of 25 percent, but they only 
>   get the Armor rating; they do not get any of the Features of the armor.
>   The Lightly Worn feature can be bought off by having the piece 
>   of Armor refit. This requires an Armorer + Logic [Mental] (10, 1 
>   hour) Extended Test and costs 10 percent of the original armor cost 
>   for each Feature the character is trying to have restored.

Do I need to refit a Newest Model every so often to avoid having it degrade into Lightly Worn and lose 20% of its armour rating? Or is Newest Model only meant to imply that purchasing the used version gets you an older model that isn't as good, and applies the -20% armour rating in addition to Lightly Worn's lack of armour features?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The term "refit" to me says it all. The Armor was not originally made to fit your body perfectly.

Therefore you would need to to refit a already worn armor, to your specific body type and form.

Therefore I would not interpret this as the need to "refit" your newly broght armor once in a while.
Although you definetly might want to have your armor checked once in a while, if it ever took a hit, since it may be damaged.

Comment: If you buy it new, it _is_ fitted to your body. My GM is under the impression, possibly from previous editions, that 'Newest Model' items degrade after you've had them for a while, but that doesn't sound right to me, so I have asked here for clarification.

Comment: I wouldn't call it "degrading" but there are reasons, why police officers and soldiers nowadays switch out their protection after it took a hit. These things get damaged when used. But it is not like it will start to fit you less and less, like "refitting" implies.

Answer (score 0):

No.

There is no system in Shadowrun 5E for Armor to degrade from use or time.  The 'Newest Model' rule only does what it says, which is reduce the Armor value if you're buying older armor that was custom fitted for someone else.